# Getting DEVICE_STATE of a trunk user in Asterisk

Tags: voip, asterisk

I am new to Asterisk. We re working on an IVR project in University and we have some queues in queues.conf file. Some of our queue members are not registered in asterisk and we re calling them via trunk. But the problem is that we cant get the DEVICE_STATE information of these devices that is noıt registered in asterisk.

For example when we use Verbose function to see the state of a device; `Verbose(${DEVICE_STATE(SIP/XXXX@10.0.0.2)})` it says the phone is INVALID.

But on the other hand we can call this phone via trunk. Is there any way to get the DEVICE_STATE of a phone which is not registered in asterisk and calling with trunk.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: I guess the question is, well what are you going to do when the device is not available? Because what I'd do is use a chain of devices to call, a la `same => n, Dial(SIP/dude/123&SIP/gal/321&SIP/guy/555)`

Answer (score 0):

you can not use DEVICE_STATE to make a call for external devices.

Answer (score 0):

The short version is no, not that I am aware of.  If the device is not registered, then Asterisk literally has no stateful information of the device.  Therefore, until Asterisk has some reason to "talk to" the SIP device in question, it doesn't even know if it's on the network.  A few quick Google searches didn't even show a way to do a pre-call SIP status enquiry.

Recommended Reading:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Function_DEVICE_STATE
http://asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/usingCustomDeviceStates.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably we will need a DEVICE_STATUS provider to get the information about external devices.